# Node.js application not serving static webpage without root path

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, web-applications

I am writing an simple application in node.js, for some reason I get the error "**TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile**" when trying to serve up my html page. This error shouldn't take place because I used an express middleware that specifies the folder where this file could be found. So why am I getting this issue?

My app structure looks like this

```
MyApp
    public
        login.html
    app.js
```

My html page is being served in app.js like this

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile("login.html");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I know to get around this, I can do "res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/login.html');" instead but I shouldn't have to since I am using a middleware. Any ideas?

Comment: That's somewhat confusing, are you expecting that Node should look in the "public" folder when you give `sendFile()` a filename? It won't, only static files when accessed directly are loaded that way, hence the name "static".

Comment: @adeneo yes, I am expecting it to look in the public folder because login.html is static

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI I am using Mac OS X El Capitan

Comment: Ok . it is the same OS tha i have...i will check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

does not do what you think it does!

It does **not** set the default folder for every Node function, in fact it doesn't do anything for other Node functions.

It simply says that if the webserver receives a request, look in that folder first to see if such a file exists, and if so, serve up that file.

Hence, it's a route for static files, most often used for CSS and JavaScript files, and of course any other static file that doesn't serve dynamic content.

However, this line

```
res.sendFile("login.html");
```

Looks for the file `login.html` in the current working directory, or in other words where you're Node script is running, it does not have anything at all to do with the static route, in fact the correct way to get that file regardless of where your script is running, is exactly to do

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/login.html');
```

as that is the correct path, which is required for `sendFile` to find the file.

Comment: wait is login.html not a static file?

Comment: @OneMoreQuestion - it sure is, if you access it like `http://mywebsite/login.html` you can even get it with a static **route**, however that doesn't make `sendFile` suddenly work with that static route that was set up *for the webserver*. Point being, the static route has nothing to do with the rest of the functions in Node, it only lets the webserver serve static files to the browser.

Comment: are you saying that "sendFile" is not the right approach is I want to use a middleware, I tried "render" as well but then I run into view engine rendering issue. Is there a better way if I want to take advantage of the middleware?

Comment: I'm saying that `sendFile` requires the correct and full path for the file, it has nothing to do with `.static("public")` at all. If you need to use `sendFile`, do so, but it won't look in `/public` for the file just because you've set up a ***static route*** !

Comment: gotcha. If I don't use sendFile, is there another way? Maybe a way that I can use the static route middleware with?

Comment: If you access the file from the browser with `http://mysite/login.html` you can use the static route, and that's the only time.

Answer (score 0):

Add function that gives you the full-path , let's call this function `$`

```
var $=(file)=>`${__dirname}/public/${file}`;
```

Then :

```
    res.sendFile($("login.html"));
```

By that, you will not need to include root path manually for each `sendFile` call .